# removeFromParentViewControllerを使っての解放について

Tags: objective-c

はじめてこの場を使用させていただきます。

現在、xcode6 objective-c を使用してゲームの開発を行っているのですが

メモリの解放がうまくいきません。

viewcontroller A から viewcontroller B への遷移後

dismissViewControllerAnimatedを B で使用しているのですが

viewcontroller A に戻った後もメモリは変わっていません。

インスタンス宣言したものを全てremoveFromSuperviewしても
全体の2割程度しか解放されませんでした。

dismissViewControllerAnimatedを使用し、BからAへと戻った後に
再度AからBへと遷移すると、
一部の変数の中身が残っている状態で様々な箇所でbad_accessが出てしまいます。

dismissViewControllerAnimatedを使用したときに
viewcontroller B の中身を全てを解放し、
再度、A から B へと遷移後、１から読み込みをしたいのですが
なんとかならないでしょうか・・・。

説明不足かもしれませんが、よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 1):

View Controllerのメモリ解放のタイミングについて、誤解があるように感じたので、確認させてください。
モーダル表示されたView Controllerは、`dismissViewControllerAnimated:`が完了したときにメモリ解放されます。`removeFromSuperview`しないと解放されないということはありません。
このことを確かめるには、「viewcontroller B」に、`dealloc()`メソッドを記述してみます。

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"ViewController B instance was released.");
}
```

viewcontroller BをReceiverとして`dismissViewControllerAnimated:`を実行すると、直後、コンソールに「ViewController B instance was released.」と出力されます。

---

モーダル表示を終了させても、メモリが期待どおり解放されていないのは、よくあるケースとして、**循環参照**が考えられます。「Objective-c ARC 循環参照」というようなキーワードでネット検索すると、循環参照に関する日本語の情報を見つけることができるでしょう。もとよりAppleの公式ドキュメントに直接あたられるなら、それに越したことはありません。